# Errorhandling in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a `mongoID` using an URI fragment as source. However, unless the URI really contains a properly formatted mongoId, I get the below error thrown.

What should I change to allow _id creation without throwing errors as wrapping it in a `try/catch` block doesn't do it?

Error:

> 500 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a
>   string of 24 hex characters in hex format

The code:

```
var _id = db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id);

this.db.users.findById(_id, function(err, doc) {
    if (!err && !!doc) { res.send(JSON.stringify(doc)); } else {res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "Not found"));}
});
```

I use the [`mongoskin`](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin#inherit-inserting) driver.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're trying to, but can you show a sample URI?

Comment: `/users/nonvalidid` - throws error. `/users/47cc67093475061e3d95369d` - valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being thrown on this line:

```
var _id = db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id);
```

If you wrap that in try/catch block it should work.

```
var _id = null
try {
  _id = db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id);
} catch (err) {
  res.send(JSON.stringify({error: "Not found"}));
  return;
}

this.db.users.findById(_id, function(err, doc) {
  if (!err) { 
    res.send(JSON.stringify(doc)); 
  } else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({error: err.message}));
  }
});
```

Does this work for you?